# I have 'No Wi-Fi Adapter Found' issue in OS Name:Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS,OS-Type:64-bit,GNOME Version:3.36.8 and it is a dual boot system with windows 7

Tags: 20.04

```
lenovo@lenovo-ThinkPad-L450:~$ lspci
```

Output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (3) I218-V (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller (rev 03)
05:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

```
lenovo@lenovo-ThinkPad-L450:~$ sudo lshw -C network
```

Output:

```
    *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (3) I218-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 03
       serial: 50:7b:9d:7e:de:d6
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.15.0-79-generic firmware=0.2-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:44 memory:f1100000-f111ffff memory:f113e000-f113efff ioport:3080(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@2:4
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 1e:91:7d:3f:58:2a
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.15.0-79-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.115.237 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: @waltinator i executed the script,but the details on the github repo of the scipt have absolutely no clue on what to do after executing the script!

Comment: Read the output of the script. The script is a compilation of all the networking checks that have benn found useful and could be automated. It should lead you towards a solution.